# Pandas DataFrame KeyError when column exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`wt_bmk4` is a column in dataframe `snapshot`, but Pandas is reporting key error.

[image]

The problem lies in the re-naming of columns in the creation of `snapshot`:

```
for key, df in dfs.items():
    snapshot = pd.merge(snapshot,df[['ticker','wt']],how='outer',on='ticker')
    snapshot.columns.values[-1] = 'wt_'+key
```

`key` is "bmk1","bmk2","bmk3","bmk4" in the loop above.

So clearly re-assigning only the last column name does not work. But how come I have `wt_bmk1`, `wt_bmk2`, `wt_bmk3` behaving normally?

Comment: It would be easier for us to reproduce if we had a code sample. It's a bit hard to work from a screen capture and with no background about the `snapshot` dataframe.

Comment: Building up on @TitouanL's comment: Can you even reproduce when creating the dataframe manually? And if not, where do you get the df from?

Comment: There is a lengthy process behind the creation of `snapshot`. It involves `pd.concat`, `pd.merge`, and *renaming of column*. I appreciate this is not helping much, but I thought the screen capture is enough to convey the strangeness. I don't see anything extraordinary about the column when printing all column names.

Comment: Please see [ask], which specifically says that screenshots of code should be avoided.

Comment: @JingweiYu Have you tried using directly the `col` variable ? Maybe there's an encoding problem preventing you from writing down the exact same key ?